# How to import pgp private key in PHP with gnupg?

Tags: php, linux, apache, gnupg

I'm need to to sign MD5-hash with previosly generated private key (private.pgp) and passphrase. (for example 123456abc) within php script that running on apache2. I'm using gnupg also.

This is how i'm doing it now:

```
<?php
 $keyring = "/pubkeys/.gnupg";  //this direcrtory owned by www-data
 putenv("GNUPGHOME=$keyring"); 

 $res = gnupg_init();
 var_dump($res); //for debug

 $info = gnupg_import($res,'private.pgp');
  var_dump($info); //for debug

 ?>
```

So, gnupg_import() returns me **false**. Why this is happening?
I've also tried to read key from a file in the same dir with this php-script, but had the same error. Please, help.

Thank you.

Comment: The manual is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php The second argument is supposed to be the data, not the filename.

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you, bro! Your advise was relly useful, now problem is solved!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are on Ubuntu/Debian based operating system this is how I would approach the situation:
**Install dependencies.**

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install software-properties-common gnupg gnupg2
3. sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
4. sudo apt-get install php7.4-{gnupg,intl,mbstring,cli,xml}

**Steps for creating a simple test script.**

1. Create a directory called **test_pgp**
2. **cd /test_pgp**
3. Generate OpenPGP keys **gpg --full-generate-key** (follow the prompt but don't
   enter a passphrase).
4. Export the public key **gpg --armor --export your_email@example.com >
   public_key.asc**
5. Export the private key **gpg --armor --export-secret-keys
   your_email@example.com >
   private_key.asc**

After executing steps **4 & 5** above you should have two files **private_key.asc** and **public_key.asc**
Now create **pgp_example.php** file on the same folder and add the following lines of code:

```
<?php
$gpg = new gnupg();

$privateAsciiKey = file_get_contents('private_key.asc');
$publicAsciiKey = file_get_contents('public_key.asc');

/**
 * import private and public keys
 */
$privateKey = $gpg->import($privateAsciiKey);
$publicKey = $gpg->import($publicAsciiKey);
$fingerprint = $publicKey['fingerprint'];
$passphrase = ''; // empty string because we didn't set a passphrase.
$plain_text = "Put Some text to encrypt here";

// catch errors
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);

// encrypt plain text
try{
    $gpg->addencryptKey($fingerprint);
    $ciphertext = $gpg->encrypt($plain_text);
    echo "\n". $ciphertext ."\n";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die('Error '.$e->getMessage());
}

// decrypt text
try{
    $gpg->adddecryptkey($fingerprint, $passphrase);
    $plain_text = $gpg->decrypt($ciphertext);
    echo "\n". $plain_text ."\n";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die('Error: '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

To execute this code open terminal and run **php pgp_example.php**

Answer (score 1):

The manual is your friend: [php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php) The second argument is supposed to be the data, not the filename.
                    – Sammitch